# import pycurl ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found

Tags: python, curl, pycurl

I've installed successfully "[curl-7.33.0-win64.msi](http://www.confusedbycode.com/curl/)" and "[pycurl-7.19.0.2.win-amd64-py2.7.exe](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/)"

I got following Error when I run the python script

```
import pycurl importError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found

  File "C:\cc_stg\Git\bugzilla\cgi-bin\newbugs_lag.py", line 3, in <module>
    import create_bugzillas
  File "C:\cc_stg\Git\bugzilla\cgi-bin\create_bugzillas.py", line 2, in <module>
    import bugzilla
  File "C:\cc_stg\Git\bugzilla\cgi-bin\bugzilla\__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from bugzilla.base import BugzillaError
  File "C:\cc_stg\Git\bugzilla\cgi-bin\bugzilla\base.py", line 19, in <module>
    import pycurl
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

I have no idea how to fix this issue. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Did you check if those versions of curl and pycurl are compatible? (from, eg. a release notes document of pycurl)

Comment: pycurl 7.19 works with curl 7.33. But that particular pre-built binary package of pycurl may not.

Comment: Also, on the linked page (the official curl download page), I don't see anything called `curl-7.33.0-win64.msi`. There's one with a `-nossl` suffix, and another with an `ssl-sspi` suffix, and some links to external pages. So… which one did you download?

Comment: I've downloaded curl from this page http://www.confusedbycode.com/curl/. I've reached this page via official page of Curl http://curl.haxx.se/dlwiz/?type=bin&os=Win32&flav=-&ver=*

Answer (score 1):

Even I had the same issue in Python 2.7.3. Later I upgraded my python to V2.7.8 which solved this.